How to make use of the Sodium Tail of the Moon?
The moon is known to have a sodium tail. How can humans on the moon to make use of them? Or they shall just let it be?

What would they use it for? If you mean as a source of sodium I imagine even the with the sparcity of it on the surface it'd be easier to mine for it than try to capture it from the very tenuous tail

I suppose "make use of" could mean both practical and scientific uses. I wonder if it could indirectly report on nuclei flux of solar wind & micro-meteoric impact rates and their variability, or perhaps a covert spaceship landing? It could also be used to make by far the world's most expensive table salt without having to be pink. Related in Astronomy: How can Mercury's sodium tail be imaged? and Why is sodium such a common ion for in ion tails?
